# How to retain the value of Select Option inside a For Loop using PHP

Tags: php

I have a working code below. Basically, the code prints the options 50 times and 4 is the default selected option.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
  if($i == 4){
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected>' . $i . '%</option>';
  }else {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '%</option>';
  }
}
```

but every time i click the submit button, the option field resets back to the selected option even though the variables was captured properly.

It would be good if the option selected by the user is preserved after the button was clicked and the only time it reset back to the selected defaults is if the page was refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the `value` is sent by `post` if not assign 4 to the variable `option`

```
<form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <select name="select">
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['select']))
  {
    $option= $_POST['select'];
  }
  else
    $option=4;
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    if($i == $option){
      echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected>' . $i . '%</option>';
    }else {
      echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '%</option>';
    }
  }

 ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="" value="Sumbit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - it uses the value sent from the client if it exists, or 4 if not.

```
if (isset($_POST['selected_value'])) {
    $selected = $_POST['selected_value'];
} else {
    $selected = 4;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
  if($i == $selected){
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected>' . $i . '%</option>';
  }else {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '%</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: the code works but it does not default to 4 which is what i want to achieve when the user refresh the page.

Comment: If you refresh, the values posted to the page are sent. If you paste the URI in the browser's address bar the default value will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Take value from posted field, say "`select`", if exist then take it as selected otherwise your default value.

Using below code:

```
$selected = (isset($_POST['select']) ? $_POST['select'] : 4);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
  if($i == $selected){
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected>' . $i . '%</option>';
  }else {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '%</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: does not default to 4 when page is displayed